# Dynamic library image doesn't contain x86_64, i386 architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, static-libraries

I'm trying to build dynamic library for iOS, combined with architectures

- armv7
- armv7s
- arm64
- i386
- x86_64

Here is my target's *Build Settings*
[image]

As you can see I've added x86_64 and i386 to *Architectures* and *Valid Architectures*, also *Build Active Architecture Only* is set to `NO`.

So after building my binary, I'm checking supported architectures by running `file myDl.dylib` in *Terminal*

```
myDl.dylib (for architecture armv7):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm  
myDl.dylib (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library
```

So it means it has been compiled for *armv7* and *arm64*, and `dlopen()` fails on simulator with error "Unsupported architecture".

What am I doing wrong?

*PS. When I use custom build script and use there "lipo" tool to create fat library, it works fine, but I don't like that way, and I want to get it normal working on Xcode.*

Answer (score 2):

Set armv7,armv7s and arm64 in valid architecture and make sure if you use any thirdparty framework that must be include 64 bit support.

Comment: and what should happen after that?