# build iOS for iphonesimulator for 64x and 32x

Tags: ios, 64-bit, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build a framework that will work with iphonesimulator on both 64-32x.

The command i'm executing is:

```
xcodebuild -target mypack -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 -configuration Release -arch i386
```

For some reason it's threw me an error when i'm trying to run this framework on a 64x project ipa using iphonesimulator.

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate question, see this answer to same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28806747/1015105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new arch called x86_64 into my framework project and then what fix for me the problem is the following command:

```
xcodebuild -target MobileCore -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 -configuration Release -arch i386 -arch x86_64
```